# What happened to my Photoshop CS3 settings?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs3

I opened up Photoshop CS3 and the resolution on the graphics is off and weird color palette options.  I reset CS3 but that did not work.

[image: pixelation]
[image]

Comment: You would need to supply more information if you want to get any answers.

Comment: OK.  Just added some screenshots of what I am seeing.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

go to image > mode > select 8 bits/channel and your done.

Answer (score 0):

Your OS X font cache may be corrupt. Have you downloaded the latest OS X patch to fix fonts?